# Filtering output and appending to a file within a line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following output:

```
{"success":true,"results":2,"total":2,"more":false,"offset":0,"hits":[{"path":"/content/dam/fr/fr-fr/frontend-testing/content-components","excerpt":"","name":"content-components","title":"Content Components","lastModified":"2019-05-16 16:01:29","created":"2020-08-19 05:13:27"},{"path":"/content/dam/ae/ae-ar/hidden/products","excerpt":"","name":"products","title":"products","created":"2020-08-19 05:14:44"}]}
```

I need to filter only parts after the path: which I successfully did"

```
e.g 
/content/dam/ae/ae-ar/hidden/products
and
/content/dam/ae/ae-ar/hidden/products
```

Now super tricky part for me is that I have to append this output to a file which content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/aem65-logistics-content-migration" mode="replace" />
    <filter root="/var/groovyconsole/scripts/aecu/logistics" mode="replace" />
     <filter root="****HERE IS WHERE THE output from the previous query must go****" mode="replace" />
</workspaceFilter>
```

So everytime a new line  should be created containing the output filter from the query.
Not sure how will that be happened with bash. That is why I ask for help.

What I did but not working so far:

```
sed '' "/<workspaceFilter version="1.0">/a \<filter root="$OUTPUT" mode="replace" > " filter.xml
```

But also new line needs to be with on the same row as other "roots"
and I get

```
sed: />/>/a \<filter root="/content/dhl/fr/fr-fr/frontend-testing/content-components": No such file or directory
sed: "/content/dhl/ae/ae-ar/hidden/products" mode="replace" > : No such file or directory
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/aem65-logistics-content-migration" mode="replace" />
    <filter root="/var/groovyconsole/scripts/aecu/logistics" mode="replace" />
</workspaceFilter
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts in form of code in their question, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two commands for it [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and awk. The first one help you to filter the content of the json file and afterward, you can use awk to analyse line by line to generate the xml content

```
$ jq .hits[].path a.out | awk '{print \
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \
   <workspaceFilter version=\"1.0\"> \
      <filter root=\"/apps/aem65-logistics-content-migration\" mode=\"replace\" /> \
      <filter root=\"/var/groovyconsole/scripts/aecu/logistics\" mode=\"replace\" /> \
      <filter root="$1" mode=\"replace\" /> \
   </workspaceFilter> \
  "}'
```

Where a.out is the json content that you have:

```
{
 "success": true,
 "results": 2,
 "total": 2,
 "more": false,
 "offset": 0,
 "hits": [
   {
    "path": "/content/dam/fr/fr-fr/frontend-testing/content-components",
    "excerpt": "",
    "name": "content-components",
    "title": "Content Components",
    "lastModified": "2019-05-16 16:01:29",
    "created": "2020-08-19 05:13:27"
   },
   {
    "path": "/content/dam/ae/ae-ar/hidden/products",
    "excerpt": "",
    "name": "products",
    "title": "products",
    "created": "2020-08-19 05:14:44"
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: That works, about the second part with the appending